# FFMPEG and HTTPS

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg lists http as a protocol when I ask: ffmpeg -protocols

Does this also mean support for a https url? Do I need to encode this url somehow for the command line. I get "No such file or directory", but with http urls (at least some) it does work.

A url (created for a Amazon S3 bucket) similar to this one does not seem to work:
https://mycompany-video-test.s3.amazonaws.com/client/btr/video/xyz0011-x403-snap-n-go-ex/1/video/baby-laugh-ripping-paper.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AVIAZL9J6SIRPAA&Expires=1323709667&Signature=pTvS9F2do2t8%3D

I suspect the format of the url is problematic, I've also tried enclosing in quotes... Yes, this URL does not currently work as it has expired, but even while its valid, its a problem.

In short:
1) Should https work?
2) Do I need to format the url somehow?

Comment: After attempting different https and http urls it certainly appears that ffmpeg does not support https.

Comment: specifically for S3 i found a way to generate an http signed url, so I've avoided this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specifically for S3 i found a way to generate an http signed url, so I've avoided this issue.